# Array conversion using JS

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

i'm new to Javascript and have sample set of array

```
[
    {
        "masterId": 56,
        "type": "Alcohol Use",
        "question": "Briefly describe any alcohol use - e.g. how many drinks a week?",
        "answer": "5 alcohol consumed in a week"
    },
    {
        "masterId": 57,
        "type": "Allergies",
        "questio": "Please list any allergies to medications or food.",
        "answer": "Skin"
    },
    {
        "masterId": 56,
        "type": "Alcohol Use",
        "questionn": "Which brand?",
        "answer": "indian Monk"
    }
]
```

basically i need to filter and convert this array based on masterId

This is an output which im expecting

```
[
    {
        "key": "Alchohol Use",
        "value": [
            {
                "question": "Briefly describe any alcohol use - e.g. how many drinks a week?",
                "answer": "5 alcohol consumed in a week"
            },
            {
                "question": "Which brand?",
                "answer": "indian Monk"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Allergies",
        "value": [
            {
                "question": "Please list any allergies to medications or food",
                "answer": "Skin"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

im new to Javascript and aware of `filter()`  method, but i can't develop a logic for above mentioned format.

Comment: please don't confuse java with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let listOfQuestions = [{
        "questionaireMasterId": 56,
        "questionaireType": "Alcohol Use",
        "questionnaireName": "Briefly describe any alcohol use - e.g. how many drinks a week?",
        "questionaireAnswer": "5 alcohol consumed in a week"
    },
    {
        "questionaireMasterId": 57,
        "questionaireType": "Allergies",
        "questionnaireName": "Please list any allergies to medications or food.",
        "questionaireAnswer": "Skin"
    },
    {
        "questionaireMasterId": 56,
        "questionaireType": "Alcohol Use",
        "questionnaireName": "Which brand?",
        "questionaireAnswer": "indian Monk"
    }
];
let questionaireTypeArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < listOfQuestions.length; i++) {
    questionaireTypeArray.push(listOfQuestions[i]['questionaireType']);
}
questionaireTypeArray = [...new Set(questionaireTypeArray)];
let finalArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < questionaireTypeArray.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push({
        key: questionaireTypeArray[i],
        value: [],
    });
}
for (let i = 0; i < listOfQuestions.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < finalArray.length; j++) {
        if (finalArray[j]["key"] == listOfQuestions[i]["questionaireType"]) {
            finalArray[j]["value"].push({
                "question": listOfQuestions[i]["questionnaireName"],
                "answer": listOfQuestions[i]["questionaireAnswer"],
            });
        }
    }
}
console.log("Welcome to Programiz!", finalArray);
```